# Can I enable List<T> polymorphism in a [Column(TypeName = "json")]

Tags: json, postgresql, entity-framework-core, polymorphism

I'm using Postgresql with Entity Framework Core via the `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL`library.

I have a property of a complex class typ that is streamed as JSON using `[Column(TypeName = "json")]`

One of the properties in this complex class looks like this.

```cs
public List<ContactInformation> ContactInformation { get; set; } = new();
```

Where the classes involved are:

```cs
public class ContactInformation
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

public class ContactTelephone : ContactInformation
{
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ContactEmail : ContactInformation
{
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can have this list of different object types serialized, deserialized as the same types, and also to be able to write LINQ such as `.Where(x => x is ContactEmail && (x as ContactEmail).EmailAddress == "me@home.com")` (or something equivalent?

I need to store a collection of information that has been collected from multiple sources (later sources overriding the values from earlier sources) and then flatten them in a structure like above - which I would like to be json because I want to easily make snapshots of the values at a specific point in time (when a search is performed and the results saved).